# Custom Activity for String Replace

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, string

In SharePoint 2010 designer, there is no direct option to replace the string with some other values. but in 2013, this is available. Is there any option to make this activity? I a column which is saving user names separated with semicolon. I need to replace this semicolon with 
tag. Please suggest me if there is any solution on this

Answer (score 2):

You can develop custom action in Visual Studio. I have article regarding that.

[Workflow (SharePoint 2013, 2010, SharePoint Online) custom action using Sandboxed Solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1021217/Workflow-SharePoint-SharePoint-Online-custom)

The example I gave in my article will not meet your requirement though you will get basic steps of creating a **Custom Action**.

## Areas to Change

- declare two parameter in `Element.xml`. Fist one will be the input string and set the `Direction` to `In` and second one the output string (set `Direction` to `Out`).
- Now in the Activity method, modify input string according to your
  liking and set it in the output string.

**Element.xml**

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="__Context" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext, 
        Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" Direction="In" DesignerType="Hide" />
    <Parameter Name="Input" Type="System.String, 
        mscorlib" Direction="In" DesignerType="ParameterNames" />
    <Parameter Name="Output" Type="System.String, 
        mscorlib" Direction="Out" DesignerType="ParameterNames" />
</Parameters>
```

**Activity method**

```
public Hashtable CustomActivity(SPUserCodeWorkflowContext context, string Input, string Output) {

}
```

Let me know for any issue!!